# Laravel how to get the data in JsonResponse

Tags: php, laravel

This is my JsonResponse, how to get the json data:{"authID":"7806176237946791"}

```
JsonResponse {#205 ▼
  #data: "{"authID":"7806176237946791"}"
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 0
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#207 ▶}
  #content: "{"authID":"7806176237946791"}"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
  +original: array:1 [▶]
  +exception: null
}
```

This is my controller

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $response = app('App\Http\Controllers\initController')->index($request);
        dd($response);
    }
```

Comment: You can see that the class of your `$response` is a `JsonResponse`, so check out the documentation for that specific class: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html. Specifically https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html#method_getData. Whenever in doubt when using Laravel, check https://laravel.com/api/5.7 to learn how to use something, including available properties, methods, etc.

Comment: @Tim Lewis  thank you for your suggestion, sometimes cannot find what exactly what I want in the documentation because I'm just new working with laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just post my answer if someone needs it.
Using getOriginalContent() method can solve my problem
https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html is a good reference here.

Comment: getOriginalContent() is working for me